# Handlebars.js if block helper ==

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

How would you change the following code to make it work? The problem is the this == 'some message' expression:

```
<ul>
  {{#each errors}}
    {{#if (this == 'some message') }}
    <li>Status</li>
    {{else}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to add a custom `if_eq` helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if(a == b) // Or === depending on your needs
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

and then adjust your template:

```
{{#if_eq this "some message"}}
    ...
{{else}}
    ...
{{/if_eq}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/d4adQ/

If your `errors` entries weren't simple strings then you could add "is this some message" flags to them and use a standard `{{#if}}` (note that adding a property directly to a string won't work that well):

```
for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; ++i)
    errors[i] = { msg: errors[i], is_status: errors[i] === 'some message' };
```

and:

```
{{#if is_status}}
    <li>Status</li>
{{else}}
    <li>{{msg}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9sFm7/

Comment: If `{{#if_eq this "some message"}}` works, why not `this.someProperty`? Can't get that to work.

Comment: @raffian: Do you have an example (perhaps a modification of one of the fiddles in the answer) of what you're trying to do?

Comment: ..was building a fiddle, then noticed my custom helper ended with `{{/if}}`, not `{{/if_eq}}`, unbelievable, wasted hours on this, but thank you for opening my eyes :-)

Comment: @raffian: No worries, some of the hardest bugs to spot are the ones right in front of your face.

Comment: I am noob in hadlebars, can i know what is 'opts' param is for ?

Comment: @ajduke: the arguments from the template are in the normal `a` and `b` arguments, `opts` Comes from Handlebars itself to give your block helper callbacks, you can `console.log(arguments)` inside your helper to get a better idea of what's in it.

Comment: @Kunok The `opts.fn` function is for the "if" branch, `opts.inverse` is for the `else` branch.

Comment: Thank you, this perfectly for me.

Answer (score 11):

Old question, but if you use Elving's [Swag Handlebars helpers library](https://github.com/elving/swag), you can use the helpers `is` and `isnt`.

Comment: This library is very useful!

Answer (score 7):

This can also be achieved by using Handlebars [Subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions).

Template -

```
    <script id="tmplStatus" type="text/x-handlebars">
        <ul>
            {{#each errors}}
                {{#if (is_status this 'some message')}}
                    <li>Status</li>
                {{else}}
                    <li>{{this}}</li>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </script>
```

Javascript -

```
var errors = [
        'Where is pancakes house?',
        'some message',
        'One cent stamp'
    ];

    Handlebars.registerHelper('is_status', function(msg, matchMsg, options) 
    {
        if(msg === matchMsg)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    });

    var tmplStatus = Handlebars.compile($('#tmplStatus').html()),
        domStatus = tmplStatus({ errors: errors });
    $('body').append(domStatus);
```

Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/techgeeek/b99qwtpw/

Comment: For reusability it would make more sense to name the helper is_equal or something to that effect, no point tying it directly to status.