# Handlebars.js Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to execute a conditional statement in my Handlebars template. The issue is it is not rendering the content at all if an if condition is inserted.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Handlebars.js example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder">This will get replaced by handlebars.js</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars.js"></script>
    <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">



        {{#names}}
        <div style="width:100%;border:2px solid red;">
        <table style="width:100%;border:2px solid black">
            <tr>
                 <td style="width:50%; border:2px solid yellow;">
                        <img src="{{itemImage}}"></img>
                </td>
               <td style="width:50%; border:2px solid green;">

                        <img src="btn_downloadAudio.png"></img><br><br>

                        <img src="btn_downloadPresentation.png"></img><br><br>
                      <img src="btn_downloadTranscript.png"></img><br><br>
                      <img src="btn_downloadVideo.png"></img><br><br>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><img src="{{itemType}}">&nbsp;
                <label style="font-weight:bolder">{{itemTitle}}</label>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                    <p>{{itemDescription}}</p>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        </div>  
        {{/names}}

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source = document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        //alert(template);

        var data = {
            names: [
            { "itemImage": "authorImage.png",
                "itemTitle": "Handlebars.js Templating for HTML",
                "itemType": "icon_document.png",
                "isAudioAvailable": "true",
                "isPresentationAvailable": "true",
                "isTranscriptAvailable": "true",
                "isVideoAvailable": "false",
                "itemDescription": "Rendeting HTML content using Javascript is always messy! Why? The HTML to be rendered is unreadable. Its too complex to manage. And - The WORST PART: It does it again and again and again! Loss: Performance, Memory, the DOM has to be re-drawn again each and every time a tag is added."}
            ]
        };

        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = template(data);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CONDITION: Display Video Button if the isVideoAvailable is true

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DAHKY/

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, rendering is fine. I want to render the video button only if "isVideoAvailable" == "true". if its false, I want to hide it. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something to be displayed conditionally, you use an `{{#if}}`:

```
{{#if isVideoAvailable}}
    <img src="btn_downloadVideo.png"><br><br>
{{/if}}
```

Of course for that to work properly, your data should make sense and `isVideoAvailable` should be a boolean value. So you'll also need to clean up your data to make sense and `isVideoAvailable` should be `true` or `false` rather than the strings `'true'` or `'false'`; preprocessing your data is quite common with Handlebars so fixing your data would be the best thing to do, fixing your data would also let you use it in a natural manner in JavaScript.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LjFr4/

But, if you insist on leaving your boolean values as strings then you could add an [`if_eq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095019/479863) helper and say:

```
{{#if_eq isVideoAvailable "true"}}
    <img src="btn_downloadVideo.png"><br><br>
{{/if_eq}}
```

Cleaning up your data would be a better idea.

Comment: I am unable to use the if_eq helper for the string type. It worked in boolean but not for string type of data. :(

Comment: @AnkitTanna: What happened when you used `if_eq` with a string and how did you use it?