# Handlebarsjs: how to get a variable in an each loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use the [Handlebars templating engine](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to compile some templates from within the browser. I now build a drop down using an each loop and I want one of the options to be selected. For this I copied a helper (from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095019/1650012)) like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if(a == b)
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

I then supply the following object to the handlebars:

```
{
    "adminUsers": [
        {
            "adminUsername": "user1"
        },
        {
            "adminUsername": "user2"
        },
        {
            "adminUsername": "user3"
        }
    ],
    "assignedAdminUser": "user2"
}
```

And in my Handlebars template I do this:

```
{{#each adminUsers}}
    {{#if_eq adminUsername assignedAdminUser }}
        <option selected>{{adminUsername}}</option>
    {{else}}
        <option>{{adminUsername}}</option>
    {{/if_eq}}
{{/each}}
```

But unfortunately none of the options is selected. The equal helper does work when I simply fill in 'a' and 'a', but somehow the assignedAdminUser isn't available within the #each loop. I can easily echo it using {{assignedAdminUser}} outside the loop, but within it doesn't seem available.

Does anybody know how I can check whether the adminUser in the loop is equal to the assigned user so that I can set that option to selected? All tips are welcome!

Comment: And I only noticed it after I posted an answer, naturally.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `each` loop, you're in the context of your `adminUser` object. These objects don't have an `assignedAdminUser` property, which is why your `if_eq` check is failing every time.

Use

```
{{#if_eq adminUsername ../assignedAdminUser}}
```

instead.