# How to use equality in handlebars build-in #if helper

Tags: node.js, templates, express, handlebars.js

In handlebars how can I say for example:

```
{{#if view_type == "medium"}}
    // Do something
{{/if}}
```

Not simply :

```
{{#if view_type}}
    // Do something
{{/if}}
```

Im am using it in NodeJs

Im looking for solution without registerHelper()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars.js if block helper ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088215/handlebars-js-if-block-helper).

Comment: You will need to build your own helper for that. Check the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no solution without a new helper. What I would suggest you is to switch from handlebars to Swig, which, the syntax, is pretty similar.

http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/

It is easily implementable.

If you are trying to do an IF I guess you are at the beginning of your project so it could be an option.