# Hide elements with handlebars depending on user role

Tags: jquery, node.js, handlebars.js, passport.js, roles

I currently have two possible users in my project which are employers and candidates.

```
var User = new Schema({
    role:String
});
```

I have certain elements on my handlebars page which I would like to hide depending on the logged in user. These elements are simply font-awesome icons and buttons. Is there a way of doing this with a helper or something? Or maybe jQuery I'm not sure, I'm using Passport.js as my login system.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing you render the page and inject the "user" variable, it's really easy to do.

You can use the if statement to render a block of code if the statement is true

[I found this link that explains it really well.](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html)

---

#### First option

[Here's a complete answer that should help you do what you want to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088215/handlebars-js-if-block-helper)
(here is what it says :).

> The easiest thing would be to add a custom if_eq helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if(a == b) // Or === depending on your needs
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this); }); and then adjust your template:

{{#if_eq this "some message"}}
    ... {{else}}
    ... {{/if_eq}}
```

> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/d4adQ/
>
> If your errors entries weren't simple strings then you could add "is
>   this some message" flags to them and use a standard {{#if}} (note that
>   adding a property directly to a string won't work that well):
>
> for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; ++i)
>       errors[i] = { msg: errors[i], is_status: errors[i] === 'some message' }; and:

```
{{#if is_status}}
    <li>Status</li> {{else}}
    <li>{{msg}}</li> {{/if}}
```

> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9sFm7/

---

#### Second option

Using Elving's [Swag Handlebars helpers library](https://github.com/elving/swag), you can use the helpers `is` and `isnt`. *Click on the link for the documentation*

#### Two examples

**is**

> Conditionally render a block if the condition is true.
>
> Parameters:

```
value [string|int] - the value to test against.
```

> Usage:

```
number = 5

{{#is number 5}}
    Kiss my shiny metal ass!
{{else}}
    Never mind :(
{{/is}}

=> Kiss my shiny metal ass!
```

**isnt**

> Conditionally render a block if the condition is false. Opposite of
>   is.
>
> Parameters:

```
value [string|int] - the value to test against.
```

> Usage:

```
number = 5

{{#isnt number 5}}
    Kiss my shiny metal ass!
{{else}}
    Never mind :(
{{/isnt}}

=> Never mind :(
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15759819)

Comment: @Raidri Thanks for telling me, I'll edit my post immediately.

Comment: Copying the text instead of inserting images for the second option would  be better, but nice addition in general.

Comment: @Raidri Indeed, I'll change that now.

Answer (score 1):

```
   {{#ifeq user.role 'admin'}} this will show only if user is admin {{/ifeq}}
```

One thing to keep in mind this will work only if the role is type string.

Comment: Answers should contain more than just code. [Here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)