# How to add "if" condition in ember 1.10 HBS for #each

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi I want to select the current month as default in the below code in Ember 1.10,
current month is a variable in the controller:

```
currentMonth: moment().format("M"),
allMonths: moment.months()
```

////// HBS ////////////

```
<select id="selectMonth">
    {{#each month in allMonths}}
        {{#if currentMonth === month}}
            <option selected="selected" value='{{_view.contentIndex}}'>{{month}}</option>   
        {{else}}
            <option value='{{_view.contentIndex}}'>{{month}}</option>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

I am getting Error for this. what is the other way we can add a if condition in this scenario.

Comment: Try to take a look to this answer it may help you to understand the #if condition : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542688/handlebar-if-condition-not-working/48545293#48545293

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Comment: take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers

Answer (score 0):

Ember uses [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), a templating language designed to be as logicless as possible. The `{{#if}}` helper just only accepts a boolean variable. For instance:

```
{{#if isCurrentMonth}}
    //current month logic
{{else}}
    //non current month logic
{{/if}}
```

Although a logicless design sounds awesome, you quickly stumble upon problems when using the `{{#each}}` helper. So most of the community quickly left the idea of completely logicless templates. Nowadays many people use the [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers).

Just install them:

```
ember install ember-truth-helpers
```

And use them:

```
{{#if (eq currentMonth month)}}
```

---

P.S. Your Ember version is very old; update to 2.18 or 2.16 LTS.