# How natively to set active menu item with metalsmith?

Tags: static-site, metalsmith

i got a simple static site with a main navigation. working with the metalsmith generator.

Is there a native way to set current menu items active?

---

#### My current unautomated solution:

I just made a workaround like following.

A MD file `page1.md` as source of content with some variables i can define at top:

```
---
title: this is the site title
currentPage1: current
layout: main.html
---

<article class="featurette">
    <p class="lead">Some content text...</p>
</article>
```

and my layout HTML file `main.html`. Where `handlebars` is used as engine.
i just post the part of the menu here:

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="/page1/" class="{{ currentPage1 }}">Link to Page1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/page2/" class="{{ currentPage2 }}">Link to Page2</a>
        </li>    
</ul>
```

both are going through the metalsmith rendering.
I got a `current` class on the Page1 in the menu.

---

#### Question

My solution is working so far, but as my site scales. I need to define the "current" for every site again and again. If I don't watch out this will lead to misconfiguration...
I do like to have freedom on my main navigation markup, as there are some specialities in. So I'm fine with creating this for new pages by myself.

Can i set active menu items somehow with the `metalsmith-permalinks` or `metalsmith-canonical` plugin or does there exists a metalsmith plugin suited for this case or maybe with another clever JS manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `metalsmith-collections` to create a collection of pages

```
.use(collections({
    pages: {
        pattern: '*.html'
    }
}))
```

Then in your template loop through them to create your links:

```
{{#each collections.pages}}
    <li>
         <a href="{{path}}" {{#if_eq ../id this.id}} class="active" {{/if_eq}}>{{title}}</a>
     </li>
 {{/each}}
```

You will need to register a block helper like this: [Handlebars.js if block helper ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088215/handlebars-js-if-block-helper)

Make sure each page ID is unique.

For example:

```
---
id: phillip
layout: base.hbs
tagline: I haven't thought of one.
pagename: phils page
href: /phil/
navorder: 3
private: true
---
```

Comment: hey, i need to try your solution the next days. `path` and `id` are variables provided with the `collections` plugin? i know for sure i don't have `path` available by default

Comment: @AndréKelling No I'd has to be specified in the page metadata and I think there might be a plugin to provide the path but I just put it on the page.

Comment: --- id: phillip layout: base.hbs tagline: I haven't thought of one. pagename: phils page href: /phil/ navorder: 3 private: true --- **edit: can't put new lines in. I will add this as an example**